# Multi dimensional array reference in struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, reference

If I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
int arr2d[2][3] = {{0,1,2}, {10,11,12}};
```

I can pass it to a function like this:

```
void foobar(int arg[][3])
```

This is not a call by value, this is call by reference, so just an pointer to the start address, but the compiler still knows it is a 2D array and I'm able to access it like one in the function.

Now how does the same work in a struct?

```
typedef struct {
  int arr2d[][3];
} Foobar_t
```

First this gives me: `error: flexible array member in otherwise empty struct`. I can fix this by doing so:

```
typedef struct {
  int dummy;
  int arr2d[][3];
} Foobar_t
```

It will compile without errors or warnings. But when I try to use it like `Foobar_t foobar = {1337, arr2d}` I get some warnings:

```
missing braces around initializer
initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

And when accessing it: `subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector`.

One dimensional arrays can easily be treated as pointers. But for multi dimensional arrays the compiler needs to know the size of the different dimensions to calculate the offsets correctly. Is there a way without cast `(int (*)[3])` and why does the syntax differ from the function parameter?

So this is the work-around I want to avoid:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int testArr[2][3] = {{0,1,2},{10,11,12}};

typedef struct {
  int *arr2d;
} Foobar_t;


int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  Foobar_t foobar = {(int*)testArr};
  int (*arr2d)[3] = (int (*)[3]) foobar.arr2d;
  printf("testStruct_0_0: %d\n", arr2d[0][0]);
  printf("testStruct_1_0: %d\n", arr2d[1][0]);

  return 1337;
}
```

Edit:

Some comments suggest that reference is not the correct word. Of course in the C language this is implemented by a pointer.
So the TLDR of this questions is: How does the syntax for a pointer type to a multi dimensional array look like.

The answer can already be seen in my work-around code. So that is all, move along, nothing to see here ;) Nevertheless thanks for the replies.

Comment: There is no reference in C

Comment: You can't have incomplete types in a structure except as the FAM at the end of a structure with at least one other member (hence your `dummy` member).  And when you have a FAM, you have to dynamically allocate the structure with the correct amount of memory.

Comment: In your workaround, your line `Foobar_t foobar = {(int*)testArr};` could be written more cleanly as `Foobar_t foobar = { &testArr[0][0] };` — no cast necessary.  The second cast is not so easily avoided.

Comment: @ Filip Kočica: If there is no reference in C, then what is the `dereference operator *` used for?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "call by reference" in the C language. Function arguments are *always* passed by value. Arrays do appear special, since an array decays to a pointer to its first element in most expressions (including function calls). This means that when an array is used as an argument in a function call, a pointer to the first element is passed to the function instead of an array; but it is the value of this pointer which is passed.

In function declarators, array types are adjusted to pointers to appropriate types. This is specific to the semantics of function declarators. Thus, a function declaration like:

```
void foobar(int arg[][3]);
```

is adjusted to take a pointer to an array of three `int`s as an argument:

```
void foobar(int (*arg)[3]);
```

In general, a type expression such as `int arg[][3]` is an *incomplete type*, since it is impossible to know the size of the array `arg[][]` without more information.

Structures in C do not allow member types to be specified with incomplete types (with one exception), since there is no way to know the size of the `struct` without this information. Further, `struct` specifiers do not make the same adjustment to array types that function declarators do, since `struct`s may actually include array members.

The exception to the incomplete type rule in `struct`s is with *flexible array members*. The last member of a `struct` with at least two named members may have an incomplete array type.

The simple solution to the problem in the question is to change the specifier for the `struct` to use a pointer to an array. Note that here the member `.arr2d` is not an array, but a pointer to an array of three `int`s:

```
typedef struct {
  int (*arr2d)[3];
} Foobar_t;
```

Comment: Call-by-reference means that data is given by a reference: here the address, that can be dereferenced by the * operator (or implicit with the -> operator for some types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `int (*arr2d)[3]` was what I was searching for. I noticed it the moment I posted the question, because in my workaround I was using that exact type...

Comment: @cubei-- I saw that you had found the solution, but not the reason that `int arr2d[][3]` would work in function declarators but not `struct` specifiers; that was the main thrust of my answer. Also, C does not have references, but pointers. Some languages use references, but in C it is always a value that is passed to a function (whether an `int`, or a pointer to an `int`, for example); the distinction is important.

Comment: @cubei-- note that arrays are not passed by reference, because there is no such thing in the C language. Arrays _decay_ to pointers to their first elements in function calls, and this pointer is _passed by value_. This is the only way that arguments are ever passed to functions in C; it can be thought of as simulated call by reference for arrays (and it is sometimes misleadingly said that arrays are passed by reference in C: they are not).

Comment: So what would be a reference that is not passed by value? Does c++ has something like that?

Comment: C++ has both pointers and references. I am not a C++ programmer, but as I understand it, while a pointer holds a value as an address, a reference also holds object alignment information. The important difference between call-by-value and call-by-reference for functions is that, with call-by-reference, `func(x)` would pass a reference to `x` to the function, and any changes would be seen in `x` from the caller. But with call-by-value (C), a _copy_ of `x` (the value of `x`) is passed into the function, so any changes to this copy remain invisible to the caller.

Comment: Eventually everything is passed as a value via a register or an the stack. A reference is a value too, here the address. By giving the address that is dereferenced in the functions body, the function does not work on a copy. The reference in c++ is only compiler magic for easier use of pointers. Reference is the generic word used for all of these.

Comment: This is beside the point. The terms _call-by-value_ and _call-by-reference_ are intended to describe the evaluation strategy for function calls at the language level. You are changing the focus to the machine level. "By giving the address that is dereferenced in the functions body, the function does not work on a copy." No; the function works _with_ a copy of the function argument. It may be that the argument is itself a pointer to some other object, [but this is not what call-by-reference means.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out just looking at the work-around showed me the solution:

```
typedef struct {
  int (*arr2d)[3];
} Foobar_t;
```

This is the correct type for a pointer to a 2D array. `type (*name)[n]` also works for function parameters.

So why is the other syntax `type name[][n]` still valid for function parameters? Probably the conflicts with the flexible array feature of structs keep it from working there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using either `int **arr2d`, which would allow you to access it via `arr2d[x][y]` or simply convert it to a one-dimensional array like `int *arr2d = malloc(2*3*sizeof(int));`.
That way, you'd need to access values like this: `arr2d[x*m + y];`, where `x` and `y` are the same of the previous example, while `m` is the size of a row.

I'd also suggest you to store both row number and column number of your 2-dimensional array into the struct.

Comment: If the type is `int**` and accessed via `arr2d[x][y]`, then how does the compiler know that y has an offset of one int and x an offset of 3 ints?

Comment: It simply doesn't know any of this; infact you should be passing extra arguments to "manually" check that you wouldn't overrun any size.
Remember though, while using int** variables, you should manually initialize every single one, like this:
`int **arr2d;`
`//n = # of rows, m = # of columns --> allocate n*m "places"`
`arr2d = (int **)malloc(n * m * sizeof(int));`
`//for each row i, allocate m "places"`
`for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){`
`arr2d[i] = (int *)malloc(m * sizeof(int));`
`}`

Comment: If it doesn't know, then an access via `arr2d[x][y]` is not possible without casting as stated above. The malloc stuff doesn't relate to the questen. Because it was stated that the array is already available and should just be referred to.